# How to increase the accuracy of Google Tag Manager form submission tag?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Forms are difficult to track due to how their validation is often very customized. My submission is undercounted as it's possible that the form event simply isn't triggering for every submission.

I set up built in function of GTM form submission, which my setting was like this:

Trigger: Type: Form Submission Form ID contains 
(I did not set Wait for tags and check validation)

```
Tag: Type : Universal Analytics
Tracking ID 
Tracking Type: Event
Category : Form Submission 
Action: Clicked Submit 
Label : page path
```

I know that the inaccuracy is part of GTM, but will I still have any extra setting? I tried to use Wait for tags and check validation, and they do not completely work, but the discrepancy seems smaller.
Or I should just use custom JS rather than using built in function for form submission?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post which form you are trying to track, so that we'd understand. There are few things you should consider while tracking form submits,

a) Validation - When you send events for every click your count would be higher than expected.
b) Try to trigger the event in the thank you page
c) if it's single page application, try to trigger it in the success message rather triggering it the button click.

or you can try this tool to track simply without writing code and send the data to google analytics events.

use the tools called action recorder, where without writing code you'd be able to send the data to google analytics.

Check out here: www.customerlabs.co